# in the greater cosmic > scheme of the universal experience?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> The Stoics acknowledged the existence of emotions as much as they
>   acknowledge any other aspect of human existence; they merely argue
>   that emotions should not be allowed to take center stage, so to speak,
>   at the expense of rationality and logic, **in the greater cosmic
>   scheme of the universal experience**.
>
> [Stoicism: A Beginner's Guide to the History & Philosophy of Stoicism]

I don't understand the bold words. Could you explain it to me!?

I think it means "when the universal experience is considered"

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Google Books has hundreds of thousands of hits for [*in the (grand) scheme of things*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22in%20the%20grand%20scheme%20of%20things%22) - an idiomatic usage that even gets its own dictionary definition...

> **in the (grand) scheme of things**  [<sub>Cambridge Dictionary</sub>](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/in-the-grand-scheme-of-things)
>    considering everything:
>    *In the scheme of things, having lots of money isn't as important as having friends.*

I assume *the universal experience* refers to some "quintessential" version of how all human beings do or should experience their existence, but it all sounds a bit waffly to me (there's not a single instance of OP's highlighted text in Google Books).

My guess is the cited writer was *thinking* of using the idiomatic standard as defined above, but decided that would be "clichéd" (showing lack of originality). Personally I think his attempt to "improve" things is a complete failure - it's not stylistically "interesting", nor does it clearly convey anything more  than standard expression.

---

TL;DR: The cited text is pointlessly verbose waffle / flannel that might more clearly have been expressed as ***all things considered, taking everything into account***.